# Can't quite get the Lexical Analyzer to work in my Java program

Tags: java, lexical-analysis, lexical

I am trying to get this piece of Java code to lexically analyze the phrase "(sum + 47) / total" and spit it out as:

```
    Next token is: 25 Next lexeme is (
    Next token is: 11 Next lexeme is sum 
    Next token is: 21 Next lexeme is +
    Next token is: 10 Next lexeme is 47
    Next token is: 26 Next lexeme is )
    Next token is: 24 Next lexeme is /
    Next token is: 11 Next lexeme is total
    Next token is: -1 Next lexeme is EOF
```

However, it comes out as this instead:

```
    Next token is: 25 Next lexeme is (
    Next token is: 11 Next lexeme is um 
    Next token is: 21 Next lexeme is +
    Next token is: 10 Next lexeme is 47
    Next token is: 24 Next lexeme is /
    Next token is: 11 Next lexeme is total
```

I know that I am screwing up something for EOF to not show up, but I cannot figure out why it cut off the "s" in sum and ")" after the 47. Here is my code for reference. Please let me know if there is anything I need to do to this post, as this is my first one.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Main
    {
       private static final int LETTER=0;
       private static final int DIGIT=1;
       private static final int UNKNOWN=99;
       private static final int EOF=-1;
       private static final int INT_LIT=10;
       private static final int IDENT=11;
       private static final int ASSIGN_OP=20;
       private static final int ADD_OP=21;
       private static final int SUB_OP=22;
       private static final int MULT_OP=23;
       private static final int DIV_OP=24;
       private static final int LEFT_PAREN=25;
       private static final int RIGHT_PAREN=26;


       private static int charClass;
       private static char lexeme[];
       private static char nextChar;
       private static int lexLen;
       private static int token;
       private static int nextToken;
       private static File file;
       private static FileInputStream fis;
       public static int lookup(char ch)
       {
           switch (ch)
           {
            case '(':
                addChar();
                nextToken = LEFT_PAREN;
                break;
            case ')':
                addChar();
                nextToken = RIGHT_PAREN;
                break;
            case '+':
                addChar();
                nextToken = ADD_OP;
                break;
            case '-':
                addChar();
                nextToken = SUB_OP;
                break;
            case '*':
                addChar();
                nextToken = MULT_OP;
                break;
            case '/':
                addChar();
                nextToken = DIV_OP;
                break;
            default:
                addChar();
                nextToken = EOF;
                break;
           }
           return nextToken;
       }
       public static void addChar()
       {
            if (lexLen <= 98)
            {
                lexeme[lexLen++] = nextChar;
                lexeme[lexLen] = 0;
            }
            else
               System.out.println("Error -lexeme is too long\n");
       }
       public static void getChar()
       {
           try
           {
           if(fis.available()>0)
           {
               nextChar=(char)fis.read();
               if(Character.isLetter(nextChar))
                   charClass=LETTER;
               else if(Character.isDigit(nextChar))
                   charClass=DIGIT;
               else
                   charClass=UNKNOWN;
           }
           else
               charClass=EOF;
      
           }
           catch(IOException e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
       public static void getNonBlank()
       {
           while(Character.isSpaceChar(nextChar))
               getChar();
  
       }
       public static int lex()
       {
           lexLen = 0;
            getNonBlank();
            switch (charClass)
            {
            /* parse identifiers */
                case LETTER:
                    addChar();
                    getChar();
                    while (charClass == LETTER || charClass == DIGIT)
                    {
                       addChar();
                       getChar();
                   }
                    nextToken = IDENT;
                    break;
                    /* parse integer literals and integers */
                case DIGIT:
                    addChar();
                    getChar();
                   while(charClass == DIGIT)
                   {
                        addChar();
                        getChar();
                   }
                   nextToken = INT_LIT;
                   break;
                /* parentheses and operators */
                case UNKNOWN:
                    lookup(nextChar);
                    getChar();
                   break;
       /* EOF */
        case EOF:
            nextToken = EOF;
            break;

           } /* end of switch */
           System.out.print("Next token is :"+nextToken+" Next lexeme is :");
           for(int i=0;i<lexLen;i++)
               System.out.print(lexeme[i]);
           System.out.println();
           return nextToken;
       }
       public static void main(String args[])
       {
                   lexLen=0;
           lexeme=new char[100];
           for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
               lexeme[i]='0';
           file = new File("input1.txt");
           if (!file.exists())
           {
                 System.out.println( "input1.txt does not exist.");
                 return;
           }
           if (!(file.isFile() && file.canRead()))
           {
                 System.out.println(file.getName() + " cannot be read.");
                 return;
                   }
           try
           {
                 fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                 char current;
                 while (fis.available() > 0)
                 {
                     getChar();
                 //   System.out.println(nextChar+" "+charClass);
                   lex();
               }
           }
           catch (IOException e)
           {
                 e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the dropped character bug and the missing EOF bug occur in this loop:

```
while (fis.available() > 0)
    {
        getChar();
        lex();
    }
```

You should be able to work out the problem by just executing that loop for a simple input on paper. (Try, for example, `()` followed by end-of-file.)

The key to both problems is that the contract for `lex` -- that is, the specification of how the world should look before and after it executes -- includes:

- *precondition* (must be true when `lex` is called): `nextChar` is the next available input character and `charClass` is its class.
- *postcondition* (`lex` guarantees that this will be true after the call): `nextChar` is the next available input character and `charClass` is its class.

Note that these are the same, which is not uncommon. That's commonly known as an *invariant*.

The contract for `getChar` on the other hand is:

- *precondition*: the values of `nextChar` and `charClass` are no longer required.
- *postcondition*: `nextChar` is the next available input character and `charClass` is its class.

It's always a good habit to explicitly document the contract for every function you write. Doing so will help you see the problems. In particular, what can you say given that the postcondition for `lex` and the precondition for `getChar` (which will be called at the beginning of the next loop iteration)?.

If you add conditions for the end-of-file indicator to the above model, you'll probably see that error as well.